# Is it possible to create a List<T> of a primitive type?

Tags: java, list, generics

Is there a way to create a list of primitive types in java (for example integers).

In C# you can just:

```
List<int> list = new List<int>();
```

In C++ there is no problem as well:

```
std::list<int> list;
```

I know you can use autoboxing in java but it will probably slow down your code. Do I need to create my own class?

Comment: No, that is not possible in Java: you need to use wrappers because of type erasure.

Comment: If you're that worried about performance, you'll have to put your primitive type in an array and give up everything that the `List`  interface gives you.

Comment: I wonder what u should do when u need memory managed dynamic array for a large collection of primitive types (someting like java ArrayList or C++ vector) becasuse according to "Core Java" authors autoboxing should be avoided for that